# How to remove error come during execution of unit test in vs 2012

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index1()
    {
        MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

            //Arrange
            MoviesController mv = new MoviesController();
            //Act
            ViewResult result = mv.Index() as ViewResult;
            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewName, "Index");


    }
```

//Controller Method is and db object create in same controller as method (Index) exist

public ActionResult Index()
        {

```
        return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }
```

//Error come as
An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: Error Comes as Index1 trew exception:

Comment: System.Data.EntityException :: "The underlying provider failed on Open." system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception:cannot attach the file <.mdf file path>